# Microphone loopback on Linux

Tags: audio, microphone

I am trying to do simple microphone loopback to immediately play to the speakers. I eventually got it working on one computer by running
`pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1`. However, a few problems.

- I could not replicate this on another 
  machine.
- This is a fairly technical process and the non-technical users I plan to provide this setup to may experience trouble if the system goes down for any reason.
- There is a background microphone hiss, which would be nice to clean up using a program rather a very simple redirection.

How would I do this in Linux in a **very** simple, user-friendly way?

A few guides suggested using pavucontrol, but I could not get it working. This is because I do not know what to do on the last setup in "output devices". After a few days of trying, I assumed those guides were old and this process no longer works - but I may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I could not replicate this on another machine.

You probably need to specify which sources and sinks to use with `module-loopback`. See the [module documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index57h3) for details.

> This is a fairly technical process and the non-technical users I plan to provide this setup to may experience trouble if the system goes down for any reason.

You can wrap the whole thing into a shell script (that also can unload existing module-loopbacks before adding a new one). Then make sure that script gets executed when the user logs in (because in their wisdom, the Pulseaudio devs don't support systemwide Pulseaudio by default).

Yes, non-technical users may still need to run the shell script again if something goes south on the system, but that shouldn't happen more frequently than other troubles non-technical users can't solve.

> There is a background microphone hiss, which would be nice to clean up using a program rather a very simple redirection.

Then instead of loading `module-loopback`, start a program that reads from the mic source, does the clean-up, and outputs to the speaker sink. Wrap it into a shell script as above.